# Unable to move correct files to the mvfiles

Tags: linux, bash, shell, linux-kernel, sh

I am trying to grep for the delimiters (comma or pipe or semicolon) in the multiple files.

If the file contains any of these delimiters then it is fine.  I want to move files that don't contain any of these delimiters to the `mvfiles` directory. The script is currently moving all the files even if the delimiters exist in the files.

```
filename=$(find /opt/interfaces/sample_check -type f \( -name "*message.txt*" -or -name "*comma2*" -or -name "*comma3*" \))
pathname=/opt/interfaces/sample_check

echo $filename
echo $pathname

if `head -1 $filename | grep -o [';']`; then

    echo "Found"
else
    mv $filename /opt/interfaces/sample_check/mvfiles
fi
```

Comment: Whats the output of $filename? Is that all the found files? In that case, if you enter your else statement, you're moving all the files that's in the $filename variable.

Comment: Hi Ivan M, that triggers me something, do I need to use elif instead of else?

Comment: There's nothing in this code that I see checking for commas or pipes. Also, why are you using backticks? Aside from that you ought to use `$()` instead, you don't appear to need them here at all.

Comment: In the code I gave only semicolon, if I achieve this I can add other delimiters (pipe and comma). In the first place I am not able to move the files that doesn't contain semicolon as the delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adjusting your logic a little. Also, include all your delimiters in your grep pattern, and tweak where you put your quotes for it.

```
pathname=/opt/interfaces/sample_check
find "$pathname" -type f \( -name "*message.txt*" -or -name "*comma[23]*" \) |
  while read -r filename
  do if sed -n '1d; 2{ /[,;|]/q0 }; q1' "$filename"
     then echo "Delimited: $filename"
     else echo "Moving ==>> $filename"
          mv "$filename" /opt/interfaces/sample_check/mvfiles/
     fi
  done
```

Since we only want to decide based on delimiters in line 2 of the file, let's use `sed` instead.

```
sed -n '1d; 2{/[,;|]/q0 }; q1'
```

`sed -n` says print nothing unless requested - we don't need any output.

`1d` deletes the first line (we're not editing, just abandoning any further processing on this line so it skips the rest of the program.)

`2{...}` says do these commands only on line 2. `/[,;|]/q0` says if the line has any comma, semicolon, or pipe, then quit with a zeo exit code to indicate success.

`q1` says if it gets here, quit with exit code of 1.

These trigger the branching of the `if`. :)

Comment: This will fail if you have file names whose names contain newlines.

Comment: True. Kiran, is that a remote likelihood here?  If so we can elaborate this a bit.

Comment: If there *might* be newlines, try a construct like `find "$pathname" ... -print0 | while read -d $'\0' filename`. I'm pretty sure null bytes are not allowed in filenames. :)

Comment: HI Paul,This script works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi Paul Hodges,I am new to this website still couldn't figure out how to access to solution. Can you please help me?

Comment: Hi Paul, I am new to this site may I know how I could accept the solution?

Comment: Good morning. There should be a checkmark on the top left of each proposed solution, below the ranking. If you click one it will mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: Hi Paul, I have another question, I am trying to specifically check the delimiters in the second line of my file so I have added the to the grep line  do if grep -q '[,;|]' "$filename" | head -n2. But this doesnt work for me. Can you please help me with this.

Comment: You specifically just want to know if the 2nd line of the file has one of these delimiters, right?

Comment: Yes I am checking how can I check specifically delimiters from the 2nd line of the files

Comment: Give me a few minutes.

Comment: Try that. This will be faster if any of the files are very big, too.

Comment: HI Paul, thanks a lot. I will try this script and let you know. :)

Comment: Hi Paul, The script works pretty well.. thank you so much :)

Comment: Hi Paul, I have added few more file names to the list then the script is not working. I also had to remove the quotes around $pathname for the script to find the files. After removing the quotes the script is working fine. But the sed command is not working. Can you please help here.

Comment: Add the changes as an update at the bottom of the original post. I'll take a look.

Comment: Hi Paul, added the changes. Could you please check.

Comment: Abc,123,xyz+Kiran.... this is how the 2nd line in the file looks like,.. afte xyz I have placed + as delimiter instead of comma,.. this file is not getting rejected.

Comment: I see no edits to your original post, and still don't understand what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid putting all file names into one variable because you would get problems if there are filenames that contain spaces. Instead I propose to read the file names line by line

```
pathname=/opt/interfaces/sample_check
echo $pathname

find "$pathname" -type f \( -name "*message.txt*" -or -name "*comma2*" -or -name "*comma3*" \) | while read filename
do

    echo $filename

    if head -1 "$filename" | grep '[;]' >/dev/null; then

        echo "Found"
    else
        mv "$filename" "$pathname/mvfiles/."
    fi
done
```

There are surely more options to solve the problem.

You can also use `grep -q '[;]'` instead of `grep '[;]' >/dev/null` on modern systems, but on old systems option `-q` might not work.

Note: I used `.../mvfiles/.` assuming `mvfiles` is an existing directory. This avoids overwriting or creating a file of the same name in case the directory should not exist. Additionally I used quotes to avoid problems with file names containing spaces.

Comment: Try `grep -q` instead of redirection to `/dev/null`, and `$(...)` instead of backticks.

Comment: the script is still moving all the files to the directory instead of just moving the files that doesnt contain (semicolon) as delimiter.

Comment: @KiranChapidi Sorry, i did not notice, that filename is a list of files. I edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using grep -L to list files that don't match.

```
find $pathname -type f \( -name "*message.txt*" -or -name "*comma2*" -or -name "*comma3*" \) | xargs egrep -L ";|,|\|" | xargs  -IX mv  X $pathname/mvfiles
```

In the above example, I use egrep  because of the pipe'd OR conditions.  That is, we want to specify multiple regexs to match.  If the file contains any of ; , |  , the filename will not be output by egrep.  This leaves only files that don't match being passed to xargs.  In the mac version of xargs, you can specify a replacement string with the -I parameter.  For every filename output by egreg, xargs will call mv <filename> $pathname/mvfiles.

As part of a follow up question, I was asked how to only review the second line of the file.  Here's a bit of code to do just that:

```
awk ' FNR == 2 && /[;|,]/ { print FILENAME } ' *
```

The above awk will display the current filename (FILENAME) when the file record number (FNR) is 2 (the second line in each file) and the input string matches the regex [;|,].

To inject that bit of code in my answer above, you can do this:

```
find $pathname -type f \( -name "*message.txt*" -or -name "*comma2*" -or -name "*comma3*" \) | xargs awk ' FNR == 2 && /[;|,]/ { print FILENAME } '   | xargs  -IX mv  X $pathname/mvfiles
```

So above, I replaced the 'xargs egrep'  with 'xargs awk'.  Also, I removed the * from the end of awk command because that's basically xargs default function - to take all of the input on stdin and provide it as input to the command ( in this case, awk ).

Since we are using awk, we can actually avoid the last use of xargs to move the files.  Instead, we can build the commands and pipe them to bash (or some shell).

Here's a version where we pipe commands to bash:

```
find $pathname -type f \( -name "*message.txt*" -or -name "*comma2*" -or -name "*comma3*" \) | xargs awk ' FNR == 2 && /[;|,]/ { print "mv " FILENAME  " '$pathname'/mvfiles" } '   | bash
```

If you want to just debug the above statement without taking actions, you can remove the bash command at the end to leave this debug version:

Debug version (doesn't move files - only prints mv commands):

```
find $pathname -type f \( -name "*message.txt*" -or -name "*comma2*" -or -name "*comma3*" \) | xargs awk ' FNR == 2 && /[;|,]/ { print "mv " FILENAME  " '$pathname'/mvfiles" } '
```

Comment: Hi Mark, If I want to search for the delimiters in just 2nd line of the files.. Where do I need to update the script. Can you please let me know.

Comment: @KiranChapidi - I've added a little explanation on how to look at only the second line in the files.

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand, you want to loop through a list of filenames that matches your search then check their content to see if it contains either a pipe, comma or semicolon. If that's the case you can use this.

```
# pathname is your directory you want files to search in
pathname=/opt/interfaces/sample_check

# here you can add different filenames that you want to match. I.e. only take files in the loop which contain filename1 in the name, or starts with filename2, or starts with filename3.
find $pathname -type f \( -name "*filename1*" -or -name "filename2*" -or -name "filename3*" \) -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    if grep -e '[|;,]' "$file"
      then
        echo "Found in $file."
    else
        echo "Not found in $file. Moving to directory xxx."
        mv "$file" /opt/interfaces/sample_check/mvfiles
    fi
done
```

Comment: You start nicely, but the [useless `cat`](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat), the [broken quoting](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable), and the [unidiomatic `$?` comparison](/a/27501200/874188) ruin it.

Comment: [DON'T USE CAT this way!](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat) `grep -e '[|;,]' $file` will open the file. *Don't* use `cat` when you don't need it, lol... Also, I suspect the `'` should be outside the `[]`, yes?

Comment: The quoting is still wrong. You need double quotes around `"$file"` everywhere.

Comment: Hi, I would like to search for the delimiters comma pipe and semicolon exist or not just only in the 2nd line of the each file. If not exist move files to mvfiles folder. Where in the script I can make changes, can you please let me know.